# I'm getting odd output from XOR. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor

I'm working on a basic encryption program (New in programming). At this very moment, I'm trying to XOR 2 hex values to create a cipher text. The problem is, my output is giving me odd data.

For example 0x61  XOR 0x2a should give me 4b according to an online xor calculator, but in my program I get odd outputs. Can some one explain why my output is not 4b and etc and how to properly fix it?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>


    char my_string[5]="0x61, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x69, 0x64";
    char my_key[5]=   "0x2a, 0x44, 0x23, 0x01, 0x46";

    char cText;


    int main()
    {
    int i;



    for( i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cText = my_string[i]^my_key[i];

        printf(" %i . The Cipher Text is %0x \n", i + 1, cText);


    }
    return;
    }
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: The value of the string "0x61" is not the same as the hex number 0x61. You should use numeric data types instead of strings.

Comment: To Jerry: I get 00, 00, 04, 50, 00

Comment: To A-- : I see! I thought 0x61 in my string was the same as 0x61 in hex, Can you give me an example using hex 61 with XOR hex 2a to get 4b? Thank you guys for your time!

Comment: BTW in your format string, a 0 there is a flag requesting leading zeros to fill the field width. If you want leading zeros, add a field width, eg "%02x". If you want a 0x prefix, you can use the # flag or just put it in the format string like " 0x%02x". See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Thanks Jerry for the infor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string initializations are invalid — you are initializing the strings with the literal text `"0x61, 0x6e…"`, not with the hexadecimal values 0x61, 0x6e, etc.

To initialize a character array with numeric values, use curly braces instead of quotation marks:

```
char my_string[5]= { 0x61, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x69, 0x64 };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely forgot all about the brackets.